# Will creating subcomponents increase bundle size?

Tags: angular, performance, angular-cli

I am currently considering whether to break one of my components up into three seperate subcomponents. This would make the TS/HTML smaller and more manageable.

Will adding these extra components increase the bundle size of my Angular 5 application? For ref, I am using AOT compilation.

Comment: You should try it and test it.  It's not hard to figure out.  My personal recommendation is to modularize as much as possible, which is something Angular is good at and without knowing if there's any difference I'd beckon to guess it's very minimal in change.

Answer (score 0):

it will surely increase, but it will be almost imperceptible.